# how to skip graph chunks with xplot/plotly, in F#?

Tags: f#, plotly

When I do a graph with xplot, I provide lists of values like this:

```
Scatter(x = [1;2;3;4], y = [10;20;30;40])
```

but what if I want to skip some parts of the graph?

how can I do an equivalent of:

```
Scatter(x = [1;2;3;4], y = [10;20;nan;40])
```

where the line would have a gap where the nan is?

Comment: Can Scatter work with Options e.g. ```Scatter(x = [Some 1;Some 2; Some 3;Some 4], y = [Some 10;Some 20; None; Some 40])?```

Comment: @MartinFreedman, no it doesn't; it would have been nice

Answer (score 2):

I think it works exactly the same way in XPlot. Try this:

```ml
Scatter(x = [1.0;2.0;3.0;4.0], y = [10.0;20.0;nan;40.0])
    |> Chart.Plot
    |> Chart.Show
```

We can also use Martin's idea to make this work for any numeric data type:

```ml
let toFloat = function
    | Some value -> float value
    | None -> nan

let scatter x y =
    let toFloats = Seq.map toFloat
    Scatter(x = toFloats x, y = toFloats y)

scatter
    [Some 1m; Some 2m; Some 3m; Some 4m]
    [Some 10m; Some 20m; None; Some 40m]
    |> Chart.Plot
    |> Chart.Show
```

Comment: this will not work with financial data since they are in decimal format and there is no nan equivalent

Comment: OK, it's easy enough to make a little wrapper function to handle this. I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes, I have something similar right now (I'm getting data out of a C# lib, so I have nullable types, but the concept is the same). I was hoping there was a way to pass a null or some kind of delimiter in the list in order to skip some values